# Targeting setup project for .NET Framework 4 in visual studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, setup-deployment

I want to use `Visual Studio 2008`'s `setup and deployment project` to build a setup for the application which was build on `visual studio 2012`, i.e. `.NET Framework 4.X`.

I want to know if it is possible ? If it is, then how ? And, if it is not, then what is the alternative to build a .msi setup with all added prerequisites for the application (for free) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, Visual Studio 2010 does still have the Setup and Deployment project type, and is compatible with version 4.x of the Framework. If you have access to 2010, I would just open your setup project in 2010 and migrate it. Then add your 4.x project.

The other free setup option, which is what we are moving to now that 2012 has dropped support for setup projects, is [WIX](http://wixtoolset.org/). Most people will have a long initial learning curve on WIX - your first project might take a couple of days, or more if it is complicated. But once you get the hang of it, you will find it powerful, versatile, and actually rather straightforward.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support Mark, but we have now bought InstallShield finally, and it is way better than Visual Studio's setup and deployment project.